# How do I assign the selected indexes data to my ToolTips data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I finally created a example that is runnable and testable.
What I've done so far is I created two buttons, both of which show a tooltip when hovering over.

When you click a button it allows yuo to chose a item from a `Select` element.

Here is the thing..

I want to display the information about the item selected in the corresponding ToolTip.

So if I click the button `headBtn` and select the first option, Then I want the information about that selected option to display in the tooltip that shows when you hover over that button.

```js
var theArray = [];

function getHeadData() {
$("#itemSelect").empty();
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/lf0tc", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                var html = '<option id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                $('#itemSelect').append(html);
            }
            theArray = data;
        });
}

function getNeckData() {
$("#itemSelect").empty();
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/bw34w", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                var html = '<option id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                $('#itemSelect').append(html);
            }
            theArray = data;
        });
}

$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(event){
var index = $(".tooltip").index(this);
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                //HeadItem
                
                break;

                case 1:
                //NeckItem
                    
                break;
        
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        //How do I assign <h3> Item Name the value of theArray[i].Name?
        //How do I assign Item Icon the value of theArray[i].Icon?
});


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var head = document.getElementById("headBtn");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var neck = document.getElementById("neckBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
head.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    getHeadData();
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
neck.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    getNeckData();
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="tooltip" id="headBtn">Select Helmet
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="tooltip" id="neckBtn">Select Necklace
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Please Select An Item</p>
            <select id="itemSelect">
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gone another way since your solution, having only one array, can only handle one item info at a time so you have to save the data somewhere anyway.

The idea is binding a `change` listener to your dropdown and altering the tooltip after selection.

Be aware that, with your current setup, this won't respond to selecting the first item right away, since it's considered already selected and doesn't fire `change`. The simplest way get around this is by adding a placeholder option with no value and filtering it on the handler but if you don't want this placeholder element it can be done by listening to `click` instead.

```js
// Find first tooltip and save contents to a variable so we can restore it
emptyTooltip = $('.tooltiptext').first().html()

function getHeadData() {
  getData("https://api.myjson.com/bins/lf0tc")
  // Listen for changes on the 'select'. Pass the target div where to insert the result
  $('#itemSelect').change(function() {
    setData('#headBtn', $(this))
  });
}

function getNeckData() {
  getData("https://api.myjson.com/bins/bw34w")

  $('#itemSelect').change(function() {
    setData('#neckBtn', $(this))
  });
}

function getData(url) {
  /*
    Since the 'select' itself doesn't get removed from the dom, 
    still has the previous content and listener attached. 
    We remove them to avoid affecting the wrong element.
  */
  $("#itemSelect").empty().off('change');
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    // Add a placeholder 'option' so it responds to the 'change' event
    $('#itemSelect').append('<option value="">Select an item</option>');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var html = '<option value="' + i + '" data-icon="' + data[i].Icon + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
      // Collect other item statistics in the response.
      let itemStats = {};
      for (key in data[i]) {
        if ((key != 'Icon') && (key != 'Name')) {        
          itemStats[key] = data[i][key];
        }
      }
      // Convert the option to a jQuery element and attach the data.
      $html = $(html)      
      $html.data('stats', itemStats);      
      $('#itemSelect').append($html);
    }
    /*
      This renders the placeholder option unnecessary since it forces
      a selection on 'select' load. This is done to reset the tooltip
      if the user dismisses the modal without selecting anything.
      The placeholder option is what signals this, since it has no 'value'. 
      Otherwise it would force the first 'option' in the dropdown.
    */
    $('#itemSelect').trigger('change')
  });
}

/*
  target is where to insert the results
  $item is the 'select' itself. Not really necessary 
        since it always be '#itemSelect' and can be retrieved in the function.
*/
function setData(target, $item) {      
  $selection = $item.children('option:selected')
  // Get target element and corresponding tooltip
  $span = $(target).children('.tooltiptext')
  // Check if there's an actual selection or the placeholder item
  if ($selection.val() != "") {
    // Insert each element in its place
    $span.children('h3').text($selection.text())
    // Won't allow crossorigin elements
    // img = $('img').attr('src', $selection.data('icon'))
    $span.children('p').text('Icon Data')
    // Item stats accesible here
    // $selection.data('stats')
  } else {
    // No selection, reset tooltip.
    $span.html(emptyTooltip);
  }
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var head = document.getElementById("headBtn");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var neck = document.getElementById("neckBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
head.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  getHeadData();
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
neck.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  getNeckData();
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="tooltip" id="headBtn">Select Helmet
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="tooltip" id="neckBtn">Select Necklace
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Please Select An Item</p>
    <select id="itemSelect">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get other pieces of data from the json object? like.. the `Icon` property or the `AStab` property?

Comment: What about other properties? Like `AStab` also the icon property doesnt actually add the icon link

Comment: What does `Cross-Origin issue` mean?

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you give me a simple example?

Comment: Oooh! okay makes sense, can I get the `AStab property though?`

Comment: Sure, just add the params you want with `.data()` or `data-*` attributes.

Comment: That would make out like 13 attributes, cant I just pass the entire object?

Comment: @MarkDenom I've added lots of comments and implemented the collection of attributes. You still have to show them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just do it like this:

```
$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(event){
var index = $(".tooltip").index(this);
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                //HeadItem

                break;

                case 1:
                //NeckItem

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        //NEW LINES
        $("#headBtn > .tooltiptext > h3.radio").html(theArray[index].Name;
        $("#headBtn > .tooltiptext > p.radio").html(theArray[index].Icon;
});
```

Comment: That changed every item I hover over though, I only want to display helm data when hovering over the helm button

Comment: Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @MarkDenom Yes, I have just fixed my answer. Is it better?

Comment: Also, `i` is not defined

Comment: @MarkDenom Fixed now, any better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I added a var for headTip and neckTip. OnChange event (that I bind on modal show) I am assigning this value. Then I am simply replacing the h3 there.

```js
var theArray = [];
var headTip, neckTip;

function getHeadData() {
$("#itemSelect").empty();
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/lf0tc", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                var html = '<option id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                $('#itemSelect').append(html);
            }
            theArray = data;
        });
}

function getNeckData() {
$("#itemSelect").empty();
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/bw34w", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                var html = '<option id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                $('#itemSelect').append(html);
            }
            theArray = data;
        });
}

$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(event){
var index = $(".tooltip").index(this);
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                //HeadItem
                $(".tooltip h3").html(headTip);
                break;

                case 1:
                //NeckItem
                $(".tooltip h3").html(neckTip);
                break;
        
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        //How do I assign <h3> Item Name the value of theArray[i].Name?
        //How do I assign Item Icon the value of theArray[i].Icon?
});


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var head = document.getElementById("headBtn");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var neck = document.getElementById("neckBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
head.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    getHeadData();
    $("#itemSelect").off("change").on("change", function(e){
        headTip = $(e.currentTarget).val()
    });
}

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
neck.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    getNeckData();
        $("#itemSelect").off("change").on("change", function(e){
        neckTip = $(e.currentTarget).val()
    });
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="tooltip" id="headBtn">Select Helmet
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="tooltip" id="neckBtn">Select Necklace
<div class="tooltiptext">
  <h3 class=radio> Item Name </h3>  
  <p class=radio> Icon </p>
  </div>
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Please Select An Item</p>
            <select id="itemSelect">
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```